# How to read constituency based parse tree

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, parse-tree

I have a corpus of sentences that were preprocessed by Stanford's [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) systems. One of the things it provides is the sentence's Parse Tree (Constituency-based). While I can understand a parse tree when it's drawn (like a tree), I'm not sure how to read it in this format:

E.g.:

```
          (ROOT
          (FRAG
          (NP (NN sent28))
          (: :)
          (S
          (NP (NNP Rome))
          (VP (VBZ is)
          (PP (IN in)
          (NP
          (NP (NNP Lazio) (NN province))
          (CC and)
          (NP
          (NP (NNP Naples))
          (PP (IN in)
          (NP (NNP Campania))))))))
          (. .)))
```

The original sentence is:

```
sent28: Rome is in Lazio province and Naples in Campania .
```

How am I supposed to read this tree, or alternatively, is there a code (in python) that does it properly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NLTK` has a class for reading parse trees: `nltk.tree.Tree`. The relevant method is called `fromstring`. You can then iterate its subtrees, leaves, etc...

As an aside: you might want to remove the bit that says `sent28:` as it confuses the parser (it's also not a part of the sentence). You are not getting a full parse tree, but just a sentence fragment.

Comment: Thank you! and I added `from nltk.draw.tree import draw_trees
>>> draw_trees(tree)` to visualize it as a real tree :-) [Oh and I can't take off `sent28`, it's part of an assignment...]

Comment: Forgot to say:  `Tree.pprint` is also very handy

Answer (score -3):

You can just use stanford parser like:

```
sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents(["Hello, My name is Melroy.", "What is your name?"])  #probably raw_parse(just a string) or parse_sents(list but has been splited)
for line in sentences:
    for sentence in line:
        ***sentence.draw()***
```