# How can I easily draw a parse tree from Stanford parsing data in python?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, parse-tree

So I have this Stanford-style parsing of an english sentence:

```
"There is a tree behind a car"
Parse: [S [NP There_EX NP] [VP is_VBZ [NP [NP a_DT tree_NN NP] [PP behind_IN [NP a_DT car_NN NP] PP] NP] VP] S]
```

I want to use some of the tree drawing methods in python to draw a parsing tree from the data.

Is there an easy way to use that parsing representation to draw a tree with python or should I change the representation somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read constituency based parse tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674417/how-to-read-constituency-based-parse-tree)

Comment: This problem requires 2 steps : 1. read the data format into a tree structure ([related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28674417/1449460) is exactly that) ; 2. draw the tree using the tree library. So... looks to me like a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NLTK has a `tree` module. You can use it to parse the representation you get out of Stanford (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674417/how-to-read-constituency-based-parse-tree/28674667#28674667)). Then you can use `nltk.tree.draw` to display it.

Comment: I tried passing the parsing output to the tree module on python but it's not the required format so I get an error. I was looking for a way to do it without having to change the entire format of the input since I'm not sure how to do it. Or at least a way to change the format easily.

Comment: How did you get this output? It doesn't look like what Stanford outputs normally. There must be a parameter to control the format. If there isn't,  you'll have to replace square brackets with round ones, and then split off PoS tags and place them before each token. See format in linked question- the is pretty much the norm.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the parsing representation of the tree (and export its resulting visualization), you can alternatively use the [Constituent Treelib](https://github.com/Halvani/Constituent-Treelib) library (`pip install constituent-treelib`).

Here are the necessary steps:

```py
from constituent_treelib import ConstituentTree

# First, define the sentence that should be parsed
sentence = "There is a tree behind a car"

# Define the considered language with respect to the underlying spaCy and benepar models 
language = ConstituentTree.Language.English

# Specify the desired model for this language ("Small" is selected by default)
spacy_model_size = ConstituentTree.SpacyModelSize.Medium

# Create the NLP pipeline required to instantiate a ConstituentTree object
nlp = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(language, spacy_model_size) 

# If you wish, instruct the library to download and install the models automatically
# nlp = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(language, spacy_model_size, download_models=True) 

# Instantiate a ConstituentTree object and pass it the parsed sentence as well as the NLP pipeline
tree = ConstituentTree(sentence, nlp)

# Finally, draw the tree and export its visualization to a PDF file  
tree.export_tree("my_tree.pdf")
```

And here is the result...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert the parse into a representation that is understandable by graphviz. Then pass that representation to graphviz. There's also an interefacing library called pygraphviz.